# Why isn't my code to select the latest non null value for a column and fill in the nulls not working?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table T1 that has daily snapshots of products and their statuses:

| SnapshotDate | ProductId | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-03 | 1 | Sold |
| 2022-01-02 | 1 | Pending |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | In_Stock |
| 2022-01-03 | 2 | Null |
| 2022-01-02 | 2 | Null |
| 2022-01-01 | 2 | Sold |
| 2022-01-03 | 3 | Null |
| 2022-01-02 | 3 | Null |
| 2022-01-01 | 3 | Pending |

I want to write code that detects the latest status for each product and fills it in for every row, in cases where it's null it would select the latest option that is not null. The final output should be:

| SnapshotDate | ProductId | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-03 | 1 | Sold |
| 2022-01-02 | 1 | Sold |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | Sold |
| 2022-01-03 | 2 | Sold |
| 2022-01-02 | 2 | Sold |
| 2022-01-01 | 2 | Sold |
| 2022-01-03 | 3 | Pending |
| 2022-01-02 | 3 | Pending |
| 2022-01-01 | 3 | Pending |

I wrote this code but it does not work for some reason, does anybody know why and how I can fix it?

```
 SELECT 
    SnapshotDate, 
    ProductId, 
    COALESCE(Status, 
      LAG(Status) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY SnapshotDate DESC)
    ) AS Status 
  FROM 
    T1
```

I've also tried Lead and that does not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `LAST_VALUE` + `IGNORE NULLS` modifier, instead of `LAG`.

```
SELECT SnapshotDate, 
       ProductId, 
       COALESCE(Status, 
                LAST_VALUE(Status IGNORE NULLS) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY ProductId 
                    ORDER BY SnapshotDate
                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
       ) AS Status 
FROM T1
```